# Powershell - Specify credential using invokeMethod()

Tags: powershell, import, sccm

I'm trying to create a script to add computer objects to SCCM. Long story short, I can't use the cmdlets found in the SCCM module as I need to invoke the command so that different credentials can be used.

I can't for the life of me figure out where to specify the credentials to use or if its even possible. Below are a couple samples of how i'm doing this.

```
    $CSVLocation = #Combo box item, will fill in later
$CSVImport = Import-Csv $CSVLocation

#Initialize connection to the SCCM 2012 Environment
$ScopeOptions = $Null
$Scope = New-Object System.Management.ManagementScope -ArgumentList "\\$SiteServer\root\sms\site_$SiteCode",$ScopeOptions
$Null = $Scope.Connect()
$Site = New-Object System.Management.ManagementClass -ArgumentList $Scope,'SMS_Site',$Null

foreach ($Computer in $CSVImport)
{
    if ($Computer.MAC)
    {
        $MethodName = 'ImportMachineEntry'
        $InParams = $Site.GetMethodParameters($MethodName)
        $InParams.MACAddress = $Computer.Mac
        $InParams.NetbiosName = $Computer.Name
        $InParams.OverwriteExistingRecord = $true
        $CMComputer = $Site.InvokeMethod($MethodName, $InParams, $Null)
    }
    elseif ($Computer.GUID)
    {
        $MethodName = 'ImportMachineEntry'
        $InParams = $Site.GetMethodParameters($MethodName)
        $InParams.SMBIOSGUID = $Computer.GUID
        $InParams.NetbiosName = $Computer.Name
        $InParams.OverwriteExistingRecord = $true
        $CMComputer = $Site.InvokeMethod($MethodName, $InParams, $Null)
    }
}
```

The above syntax is how i'd prefer to do it, just seems cleaner to me. I've also been playing with the below method which works for importing via mac address. Not sure yet which positional param is for the GUID.

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -Credential $Credential -Namespace root/SMS/site_$($SiteCode) -Class SMS_Site -Name ImportMachineEntry -ArgumentList @($null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $Computer.mac, $null, $Computer.name, $True, $null, $null) -ComputerName $SiteServer
```

Worst case i'll use the second snippet to do what I need. Was just hoping someone could confirm if I can supply credentials via the first method and if so where and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the first method:**
If you want to use the credential, you need to do it when making the connection. For example:

```
$Scope = new-object system.management.managementscope
$Scope.path = "\\$SiteServer\root\sms\site_$SiteCode"
$options = $Scope.Options
$Options.Username = 'domain\user'
$Options.Password = 'Password'
```

The above store the password as clear text which is really risky, just for example.

**For your second method:**
 the BIOS Guid position is like below:  (11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111 is your BIOS Guid)

```
-ArgumentList @($null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $Computer.mac, $null, $Computer.name, $True,'11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111', $null)
```

Comment: I can't believe i missed that in the scope options, i was so centered around the params for the invoke. Digging into that it looks like there is a $scope.options.securepassword which is probably better to use.

Comment: Glad that it helps.